# How to ensure RESTful API is called by the dedicated application (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, security

I have a RESTful API (http://192.168.123.222/apple/api/AuthorizeDocument) and a WPF application (abc.exe)

The HTTP Request is called to Authorize a document by the following JSON :

> {UserId: "1234" , AuthToken: "1354654", DocId: "123"}

Is there anyway to ensure the HTTP Request is processed only if the Request is called from abc.exe?

Answer (score 1):

If `abc.exe` applications are installed at predefined locations - you can limit access to your api only from those locations (ip addresses) with firewall of your choice.

If that is not the case - there is not much you can do to limit calls only to that application. Of course you can hardcode some "secret" inside your application and require that "secret" to be passed to api, but that's not really a protection because anyone can get that secret either by decompiling application or by sniffing the traffic (https won't help here) and extracting that "secret" this way.

Depending on how important is such protection you might use more sophisticated ways, such as providing every application user with a different "license key". On first startup "license key" should be registered on server and is related to the ip address registration was made from. After registration, given license key can only be used to make calls from given ip address, and you require valid (known) license key to make calls to the api.

None of such methods are 100% secure though.